# How to position <span> elements under each other based on the width of the <span> element

Tags: javascript, css

This will sound pretty basic and stupid question, but I have to get this working hence asked on this channel.
I have elements in a `span` that I want to place next to each other, I have a width for the `span` element. I want the elements in that span to respect the width and when they grow beyond that I want them to fall on to the next line.

```
 <div class="text">
     <span>
    eel1
    </span>
    <span>
    eel1
    </span>
    <span>
    eel1
    </span>
    <span>
    eel1
    </span>
  </div>
// these values are array of strings that I populate inside this span
```

this is how it currently looks:

https://jsfiddle.net/gpjcutr9/2/

so I'm looking at getting this as output.

```
ele1, ele2, ele3,
ele4, ele5, ele6
```

So depending on the width of the `span` I want to be able to show that many elements in one line. Also since this is not static HTML and is dynamically generated `spans` for these elements.

Thanks!

Comment: *I want the elements in that span to respect the width and when they grow beyond that I want them to fall on to the next line.* --> this is already the default behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `clear: left;` from span in your css. That's saying that each span element shouldn't allow floating elements on their left causing the spans to go to the next line.

Also change the width of the test class. At 20px, it is too small to fit the span elements.

Your css should look something like this:

```
span {
  float: left;
}
.test {
  width: 100%;
}
.spanWidth {
  width: 80px;
}
```